# How to perform a cold reset on a smart card reader in python?

Tags: python, smartcard

I am brand new to python so I hope I am providing the right information.
I have a python script which imports the following:

```
from smartcard.CardType import AnyCardType
from smartcard.CardRequest import CardRequest
from smartcard.util import toHexString
from smartcard.scard import (SCARD_UNPOWER_CARD, SCARD_RESET_CARD, SCARD_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE)
from smartcard.Exceptions import CardConnectionException
from smartcard.System import readers
```

I am going to list only the lines of code that I think matter for brevity.
But keep in mind the entire script runs perfectly fine so all of my actual code is working in case I don't include a line below. But there comes a time where my script gets an error reading the sim card that is in the reader and this is actually normal. It simply means the sim card needs to "reboot" so if I manually pull the sim card out of the reader and reinsert the card then everything continues to work as normal.
What I am trying to do is figure out the proper code to simulate manually removing the card and reinserting, so I am thinking this is what I am calling a cold reset.

```
card_readers = readers()
reader = card_readers[0]
self.connection = reader.createConnection()
#self.connection.connect(disposition=SCARD_UNPOWER_CARD)
self.connection.connect(mode=SCARD_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE) #, disposition=SCARD_RESET_CARD)

... do some stuff in between

self.connection.disconnect()
```

on the line self.connection.connect() I have tried many different ways to pass in either the SCARD_RESET_CARD or SCARD_UNPOWER_CARD but no matter what I do there it does not seem to be working. Any advice on exactly how to force the reader to do a cold reset ?

Comment: A cold reset means removing power from the card. As long as there is a connection the smart card is still powered. I've used robots (from lego and actual small robot arms) for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this is independent from the programming language, but dependent on the reader or provided driver. If you can influence the reader to be used, you may simply search for one with the desired behavior.

Some remarks:

It can't be taken for granted, that the card handles cold and warm reset differently (but yours seems to do it). (Switching to a different card which does not have the distinction is only a theoretical possibility due to poor interoperability.)

Situation is even more complicated for contactless readers, where a card may be in the field, but not be the *selected* one (in terms of anti-collision resolution). When a card is deselected, it may fall into energy-saving sleep mode or fall back to reset state. Some cards/readers allow configuration in that respect, others don't.

A given reader may accept some commands to modify its behavior e. g. by commands (e. g. with CLA=0xFF), which can be sent over the standard interface but are intercepted and handled by the reader and not forwarded to the card.